# Git created branch from wrong remote Branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Completely messed up

I created remote branch `feature/id99` from master.  Then committed local changes and pushed to `feature/id99`

I was supposed to create branch from "QA" branch.

Because I branched from master, some of the code that was in master (and not in QA) is now included in my branch when I pull request to qa :-(.

How do I 1) keep the same branch "feature/id99", 2) "re-branch" from QA, 3) commit my changes into "feature/id99"?

Since no changes have been done to QA since I've been working on feature/id99, the objective should be when I pull request to QA, only my changes in "feature/id99" should appear in the request

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be easily fixed:

```
git rebase --onto=QA-branch master feature/id99
```

Asking git to put id99 on top of qa branch not carrying over revisions from master. Then it's about using `git push --force` into your remote branch because you are rewriting its history.

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0!  Saved my a#$! Did the rebase and now my branch is pointing correctly from the intended branch! Luckily, I'm getting slightly better a git; rebase is cool though I understand need to be extra careful when using it

Comment: Good for you! Once you master rebase and cherry-pick, sky is the limit!

Comment: Glad I have found this. You saved me too.